# IP printer toner bombing

Tags: networking, printing, firewall

I have a problem and am looking for a solution to prevent it. The issue is that I have an IP printer, which is fairly old, ~5 years old, and it keeps on getting "toner bombed" from people in Serbia. What we want to do is somehow hide this printer from specific IP addresses or somehow only allow specific addresses through.

What can we do? We still need this printer available online, but we need to somehow restrict its access a little bit.

Comment: does the printer have a public IP? and what brand and model?

Comment: It is an HP Laserjet 4050N. Would I be able to just put the router behind a switch/router, that can filter out IP addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the printer is behind a firewall, allow traffic only from your own domain or mac address (if you can). Use a VPN instead of exposing your printer to the outside world directly. If you need the printer opened without any form of restriction, then you will likely remain open to such attack.

P.S. It's called a Serbian toner bomb, but the people are not necessarily from Serbia :)